# How to reverse a map and group values in a list?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have the following map

```kotlin
val mapToTransform = mapOf(1 to 4, 2 to 5, 4 to 4, 6 to 3, 9 to 3)
```

I want to transform it to the map

```kotlin
val transformedMap = mapOf(3 to listOf(6,9), 4 to listOf(1,4), 5 to listOf(2))
```

My attempt is the following:

```kotlin
val attempt = mapToTransform.map{ it.value to it.key}.groupBy{it.first}
```

that gives `{4=[(4, 1), (4, 4)], 5=[(5, 2)], 3=[(3, 6), (3, 9)]}`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of groupBy that takes a `valueTransform` in addition to the `keySelector`:

```kotlin
mapToTransform.map { it.value to it.key }.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
```

But then you can simplify your first part, as you don't need to swap things up front:

```kotlin
mapToTransform.entries.groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key })
```

Comment: or `mapToTransform.entries.groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key })`

Comment: I was literally about to post that